# Convert Html div data into pdf before printing in javascript

Tags: javascript

Hi I want to print the data which is in a specific div using javascript but when i click on print page my design changes in print preview window which i don't want to be, So i am thinking that before printing the data i have to convert that data into a pdf file. How can I do that?
this is the print function.

```
<script>
    function print_precription()
    {
        var prtContent = document.getElementById("print-page");
        var WinPrint = window.open('', '', 'left=0,top=0,width=800,height=900,toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,status=0');
        WinPrint.document.write(prtContent.innerHTML);
        WinPrint.document.close();    
        WinPrint.focus();
        WinPrint.print();
        WinPrint.close();
    }
</script>
```

Here is the Div I want to print

```
<div class="post-feed1" id="print-page" >
    <h3 id="postsheading" class="post-heading">Prescription </h3>
    <div class="prescription-mainbox" >
        <div class="prescription-header" >
            <div class="doc-bio" >
                <?php 
                    $array=get_prescription_details();
                    $array=mysqli_fetch_array($array);
                ?>
                <h4 class="h-name"><?php echo $array['hospital']; ?></h4>
                <h5 class="d-name">Dr.<?php echo $array['dname']; ?></h5>
                <h5 class="d-spec"><?php echo $array['specilization']; ?></h5>
                <h5 class="d-no"><?php echo $array['doc_officeno']; ?></h5>
            </div>
        </div>                        
        <div class="patient-bio">
            <h5 class="p-name">Name : <?php echo $_SESSION['fname']." ".$_SESSION['lname']; ?></h5>
            <h5>Age : <?php echo $_SESSION['pat_age']; ?></h5>
            <div class="date">
                <label>Date :<?php  echo $array['AppointmentDate'];   ?></label> 
            </div>
            <form method="POST" action="#">
                <div class="form-div">
                    <ul class="list_medicine" id="medicine_list">
                        <li>Medicine List</li>
                        <li>Instructions</li>
                        <br >
                        <?php 
                            $medicinelist=fetch_medicine();
                            while($rs=mysqli_fetch_array($medicinelist)){
                                $med=$rs['medicine'];
                                $ins=$rs['description'];
                                echo "<li class='medi'>$med</li>";
                                echo "<li class='instruction'>$ins</li><br>";
                            }
                        ?>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!--End of form-div------------>
        <div class="print-save-button">
            <input class="button"  type="submit" onclick="print_precription()" value="Print Prescription" />
        </div>
    </form>
    <!--  </div> End of prescription-main------------>
</div><!--End of feeds -->
```

Comment: A **much** simpler approach would be to make sure your CSS rules apply to print media in whatever way is appropriate to your content.

Comment: @Pointy I have made this already by making seperate css file 

<link href="css/print-style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen,print" />

here i gave for both print and screen but it is not working

Comment: Well print style sheets **do** work, all the way back to IE6, though they're far from perfect. If your print style sheet is not working, then that should be the problem you work on. Converting some HTML + CSS to PDF is not an easy thing to do.

Comment: I am doing the same in print style sheet which i did in normal style sheet

Comment: perhaps you should create another question and include at least some part of your CSS and HTML for which the styles are not applied when printing. Without seeing the actual CSS it's hard to provide any assistance.

Comment: One thing: you extract that `<div>` and add it to the new window, but do you also add the `<link>` for the stylesheet to that window? If not, then that's your problem.

Comment: where i can add that link for new window which is opening for print?

Comment: I just added an answer. Basically you just `document.write()` the `<link>` tags you need into the popup window.

Answer (score 0):

“Printing” and “converting to PDF” should be the same, as one could easily print into a PDF. So actually `window.print()` will convert the print into an PDF if the user wants it that way.

All you need is some good print CSS, which is then used to either print to paper or to a PDF.

There are also some applications (e.g. [Odoo/Open ERP](https://www.odoo.com/)) that use a server install of Chromium and print stylesheet and print to a PDF printer on the server. That way you have cheap, build-in feature to generate PDFs from HTML/CSS sites without relying on a third-party service or any additional libraries.

Comment: However, if the stylesheet isn't being applied, then it won't look right.

Comment: @Pointy you are right but its not working as i apply styling to print and screen media

Comment: @Pointy “if the stylesheet isn't being applied” …than you have some other problems independently from any “convert-to-PDF/print” tasks…

Answer (score 0):

The contents of the popup window are not affected by the CSS of the main window. You have to import your styles explicitly:

```
function print_precription()
{
    var prtContent = document.getElementById("print-page");
    var WinPrint = window.open('', '', 'left=0,top=0,width=800,height=900,toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,status=0');
    WinPrint.document.write('<link href="css/print-style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen,print">');
    WinPrint.document.write(prtContent.innerHTML);
    WinPrint.document.close();  
    WinPrint.focus();
    WinPrint.print();
    WinPrint.close();
}
```